# Is there a way to code re-factor swapping integers

Tags: java, swap

We have this code in many places where we swap integers if one value is higher than the other. Is there a way to re-factor this code, so it can be re-used?

```
    int numerator2 = <some random number>;
    int denominator2 = <some random number>;

    if (numerator2 > denominator2) {
        int temp = denominator2;
        denominator2 = numerator2;
        numerator2 = temp;
    }
```

Comment: Since java doesn't support passing by reference, you can't really write a method that swaps the ints in place without at least wrapping them in some data structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your question boils down to is that you want a neat and reusable way to swap swap the values of a pair of bare variables.  (I know you want to do this conditionally, but it is easier to explain for the unconditional case.)

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this in Java.  The various programming language mechanisms that *hypothetically* could be used to do this are not available in Java.  Here's a summary:

- In some languages, you would do this using call by reference (e.g. FORTRAN) or INOUT  parameter passing (e.g. ObjectiveC):

  ```
  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  swap(a, b);
  ```
- In some languages you can simulate call by reference by passing addresses (e.g. C and C++):

  ```
  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  swap(&a, &b);
  ```
- In some languages, there is a tuple assignment statement (e.g. Perl):

  ```
  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  a, b = {b, a};
  // or ...
  a, b = swap(b, a); // where swap returns an explicit or implicit tuple.
  ```
- In some languages, procedures / methods can return multiple results and there is a special syntax to assign individual results to a different variable (e.g. Mesa ... and I'm sure there are less obscure examples):

  ```
  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  a, b = swap(b, a);
  ```

Unfortunately, none of these mechanisms are available in Java.  The best you can do is use some kind of mutable wrapper class instead of bare primitive types; e.g.

```
   IntHolder a = new IntHolder(1);
   IntHolder b = new IntHolder(2);
   swap(a, b);
```

**FOLLOWUP**

One could use existing types like `AtomicType` or Apache Commons' `MutableInteger` as the wrapper class.  I'd recommend the latter since it is marginally faster.  Besides, using `AtomicType` instances doesn't mean you can implement the `swap` method atomically.

Comment: Apache commons-lang come with MutableInt class (http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/mutable/MutableInt.html ), which would be a good idea for `IntHolder`.

Comment: @Grzegorz, Java has had built in mutable int value, AtomicInteger since 2004. Better to use a builtin type if you can.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey - it depends.  `AtomicInteger` has intrinsic overheads associated with synchronization that you might want to avoid if synchronization is unnecessary.

Comment: @Stephen C, perhaps you mean volatile? AtomicInteger is *not* synchronized.  The performance penalty is much less than synchronization, which is why it is does that way.  Using Objects instead of primitives makes much more difference.

Comment: @Stephen C, AtomicInteger was synchronized in the backport library (for Java 1.4 and earlier), but if you are using the builtin version, it is not.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey - I chose my words poorly.  I should have said thread-safe; i.e. the fact that setting an AtomicInteger *has* to flush its contents to main memory, and getting it has to fetch from memory.  While the overhead is less than a mutex, it could still be significant in some cases.

Comment: @Stephen C, if its that significant, I wouldn't use an object at all, stick with primitives.

Answer (score 3):

Create a class containing the two numbers as member variables.  It can accept these in the constructor.

Then create a method on that class that returns a new instance of the same class with the members swapped if they need to be.

Answer (score 2):

Won't the primitive types be the fastest way? Primitives are created on the stack and why engender objects?

Comment: Primitives will be much faster, however in 90% of cases the difference won't matter and simpler/clear code is more desirable.

Comment: I think the point of the question is that the OP is trying to find a way to get rid of a large amount of duplicate code.  It is a tradeoff between readability and a (relatively small) performance penalty.

Comment: I go along. The trade-off is not an overhaed in this case, I guess, while using primitives.

Answer (score 2):

A short version of @Emil's answer is

```
public static void swap(AtomicInteger i,AtomicInteger j) {
    j.set(i.getAndSet(j.get()));
}
```

However, when dealing with a lot of data often arrays, Collections or Objects are used.  In these situations you don't need an additional object just to swap values.

Comment: It should be noted that while the individual operations on the `AtomicInteger` instances are thread safe, the `swap` method is not.

Comment: @Stephen C, that is correct. You might be able to write a thread safe version with compareAndSwap.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [AtomicInteger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) or you can write your own `MutableInteger` instead of using primitive `int`.

**Code:**

```
void swap(AtomicInteger i,AtomicInteger j){
        int tmp=i.get();
        i.set(j.get());
        j.set(tmp);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AtomicInteger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), or any user created custom wrapper object that will hold the `int` value. Then you can write a `swap` method.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest sticking with the primitive version.

Reasons:

- Better performance by avoiding wrappers
- It's such a common idiom that you can mentally parse the swap code easily
- Saving 30 characters or so of typing does not justify IMHO adding an extra layer of abstraction. If you include conversion to wrapper types you possibly haven't even saved any typing at all.
- You can easily write the swap in one line if you are worried about vertical space

e.g.

```
if (numerator2 > denominator2) {
    int t = denominator2; denominator2 = numerator2; numerator2 = t;
}
```

If you like fun hacks, here is also a way of doing it in a single expression by exploiting the order of operations:

```
numerator2= denominator2+ (0&(denominator2=numerator2));
```

Of course this is not really recommended if you care about readability/maintenance :-)